# Codeigniter group sum with condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a function ini modal like below,

```
public function donation($month)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('select year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(jumlah) as total from donation group by year(date), month(date)');   
        return $query->result();
    }
```

This function working properly without condition.
I want to filter the result with `$month`.

How to make `where` condition so I can get sum of specific month.

Comment: use DATE_FORMAT in where as  `->where("DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')", "2019-11")`

Comment: I have create new function with this where format and work well.

Answer (score 0):

Specify where condition like `where MONTH(date) = $month` before `group_by`